# RewriteCond - backreference with no value

Tags: .htaccess, backreference

got this strange issue:
i'm trying to translate this address
www.mydomain.com/index.asp?pag=XXX&id=YYY
into
www.mydomain.com/XXX-YYY

i'm trying with

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pag=([^.*$]*)&id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1-%2
```

but i got "%1-%2" as result 
seems i can't properly display them, where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the displayed URL be like : `www.domain.com/XXX-YYY`!
if so,then this is the code you need:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)-(\d+)$   index.asp?page=$1&id=$2
```

if I'm wrong and misunderstood, let me know to edit the code!